# Kibana 6.2 visualisations term order

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I have a Kibana visualisation where it is ordered by term of a text field.

```
contract 1
contract 2
contract 3
contract 34
contract 35
contract 4
contract 5....
```

my issue is that it sees contract 34 and 35 the same as 3 (as an example) I can understand it logic in doing so but is there anyway to remedy this little nuance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), as opposed to numerical order. In a terms aggregation, the buckets can be order by document count, by term (your case) or by some other metric sub-aggregation.

If you have another numeric field that contains the contract number, you could eventually create a metric sub-aggregation on that numeric field and order the parent buckets according to that metric (see example below), otherwise you need to create such a field... or cope with lexicographical order.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "contracts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "contractField",
        "order": { 
          "contractNumber": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "contractNumber": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "contractNumberField"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I was hoping to to have to create an extra field but guess that's what I'm going to have to do